# Как возобновить приостановленную задачу печати на CUPS используя её библиотеки C?

Tags: c++, linux, c, debian, cups

У меня задача имеет статус *ipp_jstate_e = IPP_JOB_HELD*, т.е. приостановлена.
В *cups.h* я только нашел интерфейс *cupsCancelJob2*, с помощью которого можно отменить либо удалить задачу. А вот как продолжить печать не могу найти.
В *ipp.h* есть тип *ipp_op_e* с перечислением операций, но вот куда их передать, не понятно. Подскажите, кто знает.

Comment: может лучше по ipp с купсом общаться?

Comment: @eri может, скажите только как

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-ipp-protocol-00

Comment: А еще можно по дбас чтотт и по хттп

Comment: @eri rpc запрещено, так что дбас нет. как правильно хттп запрос для resume job составить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так поехало

```
    ipp_t* request = ::ippNewRequest(IPP_RELEASE_JOB);

    QString uri { "/jobs/" };
    uri += QString::number(job.id);

    cups_lang_t* language = ::cupsLangDefault();
    ::ippAddString(request, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_CHARSET,"attributes-charset", NULL, ::cupsLangEncoding(language));
    ::ippAddString(request, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_LANGUAGE, "attributes-natural-language", NULL, language->language);
    ::ippAddString(request, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_URI, "job-uri", NULL, qPrintable(uri));
    ::ippAddString(request, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_NAME, "requesting-user-name", NULL, job.user);
    ::ipp_t* resp = ::cupsDoRequest(http, request, qPrintable(uri));
```

Тыкните носом в ссылку, где все аттрибуты для операций расписаны.

Comment: https://www.cups.org/doc/cupspm.html - основной линк на док, если интересуют наборы констант IPP_TAG_LANGUAGE, то это в самом конце дока блок Constants

Comment: https://opensource.apple.com/source/cups/cups-33/doc/spm.html

Comment: @goldstar_labs там опять же идут перечисления этих енумераторов, но нет того, как составить код, подобный вышеуказанному.